# How to compare the JSON format array VALUE and KEY to create a new array? in Angular 5

Tags: arrays, angular, comparison

Here is my first JSON array format:

```
this.columnNames = [
  {field : "Name"},
  {field : "Address"},
  {field : "Age"}
];
```

Here is my first JSON array format:

```
this.rowData = [
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12",w :  "1",e :  "8"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15",w :  "2",e :  "7"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16",w :  "3",e :  "6"}, 
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17",w :  "4",e :  "5"},
];
```

Here I want to to compare the VALUE which is present in the first `array(columnNames)` and KEYS which is present in the second array. If it's equal, then I want to push those matching data from the second `array(rowData)` into the new array.

And I want my final result like this:

```
public rowData: any =[
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16"}, 
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17"},
];
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt at this yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grab the fields from each object in your `columnNames` array using `.map()`. Then, map each object in `rowData` to a new object created using `.reduce()`, which only includes the keys from your `fields` array:

```js
const columnNames = [
  {field : "Name"},
  {field : "Address"},
  {field : "Age"}
];

const rowData = [
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12",w :  "1",e :  "8"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15",w :  "2",e :  "7"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16",w :  "3",e :  "6"}, 
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17",w :  "4",e :  "5"},
];  

const fields = columnNames.map(({field}) => field); // get array ["Name", "Address", "Age"]
const result = rowData.map( // map each object in rowData to a new object
  o => fields.reduce((obj, k) => ({...obj, [k]: o[k]}), {})
  //    ^^ construct the new object, using reduce, spread syntax and computed property names
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

If you can support [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (which takes an array of nested `[key, value]` pairs and builds an object from them), then there is no need to use `.reduce()`:

```js
const columnNames = [
  {field : "Name"},
  {field : "Address"},
  {field : "Age"}
];

const rowData = [
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12",w :  "1",e :  "8"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15",w :  "2",e :  "7"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16",w :  "3",e :  "6"}, 
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17",w :  "4",e :  "5"},
];  

const fields = columnNames.map(({field}) => field);
const result = rowData.map( 
  o => Object.fromEntries(fields.map(k => [k, o[k]]))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `filter` your object properties based on `columnNames` array and then just create an object using `Object.fromEntries`:

```
const result = rowData.map(s => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(s).filter(([k, v]) => columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k))));
```

An example:

```js
let columnNames = [
  {field : "Name"},
  {field : "Address"},
  {field : "Age"}
];

let rowData = [
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12",w :  "1",e :  "8"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15",w :  "2",e :  "7"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16",w :  "3",e :  "6"},
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17",w :  "4",e :  "5"},
];

const result = rowData.map(s => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(s).filter(([k, v]) => columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k))));
console.log(result);
```

Or more debuggable version:

```
const result = rowData.map(s => {
  let allProperties = Object.entries(s);
  let filteredProperties = allProperties.filter(([k, v]) => 
      columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k));
  let result = Object.fromEntries(filteredProperties);
  return result;
})
```

An example:

```js
let columnNames = [
  {field : "Name"},
  {field : "Address"},
  {field : "Age"}
];

let rowData = [
  {Name : "Praveen",Address : "aiff",Age : "12",w :  "1",e :  "8"},
  {Name : "Akashay",Address : "xvn",Age : "15",w :  "2",e :  "7"},
  {Name : "Bala",Address : "hjk",Age : "16",w :  "3",e :  "6"},
  {Name : "Charu",Address : "sss",Age : "17",w :  "4",e :  "5"},
];

const result = rowData.map(s => {
  let allProperties = Object.entries(s);
  let filteredProperties = allProperties.filter(([k, v]) => 
      columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k));
  let result = Object.fromEntries(filteredProperties);
  return result;
})
```

[Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is the method which transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

The following row means that we [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `allProperies` array based on `columnNames` array.

[some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method returns `true` if some property of `columnNames` exists in `allProperties`:

```
let filteredProperties = allProperties.filter(([k, v]) => 
     columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k));
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your response. i have doubt in that, i am a beginner of angular 8 exactly i don't know what is "Object.fromEntries",and also can u please explain this one " let filteredProperties = allProperties.filter(([k, v]) => 
      columnNames.some(cl => cl.field == k));  ". Thank u in adavnce!

Comment: @StepUp Hi, I have a problem. Could you solve my problem? :) Here is the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089217/i-want-to-get-hierarchy-from-an-array-angular-8]

Answer (score 3):

Store all the field names in a variable `keys` using [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) . Then loop through the original array and create a object having the properties present in `keys`

Try like this:

```
let keys = this.columnNames.map(x => x.field);

this.rowData.forEach(item => {
  let obj = {}
  keys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = item[key]
  });
  this.result.push(obj)
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9jirp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Can u please explain what will be happening here?                                                                                             keys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = item[key]
  });

Comment: Sure, I am adding the description

Comment: @PraveenSivanadiyar Added description. let me know if this was helpful

Comment: `obj` is a new empty object. `obj[key] = item[key] ` means, taking  the first loop,key is "Name", so `obj[key]` will be `{Name: }` and `item.Name` is `Praveen`, so the result will be  `{Name: "Praveen" }`

Comment: Yeah, Now i understand and also its working fine with my code. thank u so much @Adrita Sharma.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Hi, I have a problem. Could you solve my problem? :) Here is the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089217/i-want-to-get-hierarchy-from-an-array-angular-8]