# I want to get Hierarchy from an Array - Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, comparison, hierarchy

I have an Array and One String Value. I want to get the Hierarchy of the String into an Array.

For example, I have a string value "Casuals". "Casuals" value is inside the "Shirts" object. "Shirts" value is inside the "Men" object. And "Men" value is inside the "Default Category" object. So, this is how the logic should be work.

Here is my Sample Array:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Default Category",
  "children_data": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Men",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "T-Shirts",
          "children_data": [
            {
              "id": 27,
              "name": "Polos"
            },
            {
              "id": 28,
              "name": "Tees"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "name": "Shirts",
          "children_data": [
            {
              "id": 30,
              "name": "Casuals"
            },
            {
              "id": 31,
              "name": "Formals"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Women",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 80,
          "name": "Western wears",
          "children_data": [
            {
              "id": 81,
              "name": "T-Shirts"
            },
            {
              "id": 82,
              "name": "Tank & Crop Tops"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 21,
          "name": "Ethnic wears",
          "children_data": [
            {
              "id": 51,
              "name": "Kurta & Kurtis"
            },
            {
              "id": 52,
              "name": "Kurta Sets"
            }
          ]
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have the value

> let myCategory = "**Casuals**";

So, that I want to get my final value is **["Default Category", "Men", "Shirts", "*Casuals*"]**

I'm still struggling to get the Hierarchy of the value.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: try DFS or BFS.

Comment: Show some trial code

Comment: @MustafaKunwa I don't know how to build this logic. I don't have an idea about this. Still, I'm think about it.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya What is the meaning of DFS, BFS bro?

Comment: Could you explain logic of getting  `["Default Category", "Men", "Shirts", "Casuals"]`

Comment: Depth First Search or Breadth First Search are algorithms for searching for a node in a tree. Lot of material on it on the web. Try them out and update if you are facing some errors.

Comment: @StepUp For example, I have a string value **"Casuals"**. "Casuals" value is inside the "Shirts" object. "Shirts" value is inside the "Men" object. And "Men" value is inside the "Default Category" object. So, this is how the logic should be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code for your problem. Let me know If you are facing any issue. Please see working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-eyx5c3?file=index.js).

Call `getFilterdObject(data,'Polos')`, `data` is your object.

```
function getFilterdObject(obj,param){
  let finalArray =[];  
  finalArray.push(obj.name);  
  if(obj['name'] != param && obj['children_data']){
    let filterData = obj['children_data'].filter(function search(a) {
        var children;
        if (a.name === param) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(a.children_data)) {
            return false;
        }
        children = a.children_data.filter(search);
        if (children.length) {
            a.children_data = children;
            return true; 
        } 
    });
    if(filterData.length){
      getArray(filterData, param);
    }
    else{
      finalArray =[];
    }
  }

  function getArray(obj,param){
    if(obj.length){     
      obj.map((val)=>{  
        finalArray.push(val.name);
        if(val.children_data && val.name != param){
          getArray(val.children_data, param);  
        }
      }); 
    }  
 }
   return finalArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use `Depth First Search Algorithm` to recursively search a higher object and then use recursive approach to find all parents:

```
// Depth First Search Algorithm
function getParentNodeByChild(obj, nameToFind) {
    if (obj.children_data) {
       if (obj.children_data.some(ch => ch.name == nameToFind))
           return obj;
       else {
           for (let item of obj.children_data) {
               if (item.children_data) {
                   let check = this.getParentNodeByChild(item, nameToFind)
                   if (check) {
                       return check;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    }
    return null
}


function getParentObject(nameToFind) {
    let parentObj;
    if (obj.children_data && obj.children_data.some(ch => ch.name == nameToFind))
        return obj;
    else {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.children_data.length; ++i) {
            parentObj = getParentNodeByChild(obj.children_data[i], nameToFind);
            if (parentObj)
                break;
        }
        return parentObj;
    }
 }

const getAllNames = keyName => {
    const parentObject = getParentObject(keyName);
    if (parentObject != null && parentObject.name != null) {
        names.push(parentObject.name)
        getAllNames(parentObject.name);
    }
}

let names = [];
let keyToFind = 'Casuals';
getAllNames(keyToFind);
names.push(keyToFind);
console.log(`names`, names);
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Default Category",
  "children_data": [
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Men",
  "children_data": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "T-Shirts",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 27,
          "name": "Polos"
        },
        {
          "id": 28,
          "name": "Tees"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Shirts",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 30,
          "name": "Casuals"
        },
        {
          "id": 31,
          "name": "Formals"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Women",
  "children_data": [
    {
      "id": 80,
      "name": "Western wears",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 81,
          "name": "T-Shirts"
        },
        {
          "id": 82,
          "name": "Tank & Crop Tops"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "Ethnic wears",
      "children_data": [
        {
          "id": 51,
          "name": "Kurta & Kurtis"
        },
        {
          "id": 52,
          "name": "Kurta Sets"
        }
      ]
   }
  ]
}
  ]
};


// Depth First Search Algorithm
function getParentNodeByChild(obj, nameToFind) {
  if (obj.children_data) {
  if (obj.children_data.some(ch => ch.name == nameToFind))
      return obj;
  else {
      for (let item of obj.children_data) {
          if (item.children_data) {
              let check = this.getParentNodeByChild(item, nameToFind)
              if (check) {
                  return check;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  }
  return null
}


function getParentObject(nameToFind) {
  let parentObj;
  if (obj.children_data && obj.children_data.some(ch => ch.name == nameToFind))
return obj;
  else {
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.children_data.length; ++i) {
      parentObj = getParentNodeByChild(obj.children_data[i], nameToFind);
      if (parentObj)
          break;
  }
  return parentObj;
  }
}


const getAllNames = keyName => {
const parentObject = getParentObject(keyName);
if (parentObject != null && parentObject.name != null) {
  names.push(parentObject.name)
  getAllNames(parentObject.name);
}
}

let names = [];
let keyToFind = 'Casuals';
getAllNames(keyToFind);
names.push(keyToFind);
console.log(`names`, names);
```